# git CRLF and encoding

Tags: git, newline

I'm fighting against the tool and loosing. I want my project for every text file and every developer to be UTF-8 and CRLF. 
1) how do I configure git for that ?
2) how do I share this git setting with all developers so that nobody can forget to configure that ?

I read a bit about core.autocrlf and safecrlf, but I don't see how it's relevant to my problem.

Thanks all.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  One of the best features of version control systems is letting people on different platforms (with different line endings) can work together.  The UTF-8 part seems reasonable.

Comment: because I want standard tools (we're trying to do agile stuff). And I have freshmen as coworkers, so I decide for them. Moreover, we can try customization as soon as standardisation works. For now, nothing works and I see commit battle on the line endings. And myself as the lead dev I don't know how to configure everything.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [pre-commit hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) that checks for the presence of CRLF, which everyone (and the integrator in particular) puts in their `.git/hooks/` directory.  For example, checking the tree for `! grep -qPrI '[^\r]$' .` (if your grep supports `-P`) (caveat: I didn't *really* test that expression).  By the same token, you could also write a hook that checks that all files are valid UTF-8.

That said, I think that `core.autocrlf` (see [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)) sounds more like the solution for your CRLF problem; this way all files in the repository will have LF, and whoever has tools that generate CRLF won't mess up things.  On the encoding side, avoid non-ASCII, or if that's not possible, make sure everyone's tools are configured for UTF-8.

The most important point for rule-checking (like for line endings and encodings) is the integrator (that is, the one whom everyone clones from).  If the integrator just refuses to merge commits that break line endings etc., most disruption can be avoided (though contributors still have to set up their tools, obviously).

> how do I share this git setting with all developers so that nobody can forget to configure that ?

You can distribute your `.git/config` or `~/.gitconfig` (or the relevant entries in it).  I don't think it's possible to automatically distribute settings through `git clone`.